# Dimension too large problem tizpicture

Tags: pgfplots, dimension-expressions

I'm a beginner with LaTeX. I use `matlab2tikz` to create a bar figure, but in LaTeX always shows `Dimension too large.end{\axis}`. I have no idea about that.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4in,
height=2.5in,
at={(0.634in,4.176in)},
scale only axis,
bar shift auto,
xmin=0,
xmax=24,
restrict y to domain= 0:5000,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Segments Number},
ymin=0,
ymax=4420,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={Length},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Group 1}
]
\addplot[ybar, bar width=0.9, fill=mycolor1, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
1   4000\\
2   4159\\
3   3217\\
4   3217\\
5   3004\\
6   3379\\
7   4320\\
8   3121\\
9   2796\\
10  3407\\
11  3919\\
12  3942\\
13  3619\\
14  1506\\
15  3506\\
16  3783\\
17  3451\\
18  3842\\
19  4127\\
20  3450\\
21  3246\\
22  3766\\
2   3196\\
};
\addplot[forget plot, color=white!15!black] table[row sep=crcr] {%
0   0\\
24  0\\
};
\addplot [color=red, dashed, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
14  0\\
14  1506\\
};
\addplot [color=red, dashed, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   1506\\
14  1506\\
};
\addplot [color=red, dashed, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
7   0\\
7   4320\\
};
\addplot [color=red, dashed, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   4320\\
7   4320\\
};
\addplot [color=blue, dashed, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   3477.08695652174\\
3477.08695652174    3477.08695652174\\
};
\node[above, align=center]
at (axis cs:12,3477) {Average Segments Length};
\end{axis}
```

Comment: ` Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The last plot has a very large x value. Without it the plots compiles fine. This looks like an error.

Answer (score -1):

Refering to the valid comment from [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer), you get a result with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
        width=4in,
        height=2.5in,
        at={(0.634in,4.176in)},
        scale only axis,
        bar shift auto,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=24,
        restrict y to domain= 0:5000,
        xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        xlabel={Segments Number},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=4420,
        ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        ylabel={Length},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        title style={font=\bfseries},
        title={Group 1}
    ]
\addplot[ybar, bar width=0.9, fill=blue, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
1   4000\\
2   4159\\
3   3217\\
4   3217\\
5   3004\\
6   3379\\
7   4320\\
8   3121\\
9   2796\\
10  3407\\
11  3919\\
12  3942\\
13  3619\\
14  1506\\
15  3506\\
16  3783\\
17  3451\\
18  3842\\
19  4127\\
20  3450\\
21  3246\\
22  3766\\
23  3196\\
};

\addplot [color=red, dashed, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   1506\\
14  1506\\
};


\addplot [color=red, dashed, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   4320\\
7   4320\\
};

\node[above, align=center, yshift=.6cm]
    at (axis cs:13,3477) {Average Segments Length};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]